# Why are my photos slightly yellower than they should be on iPad 1st gen?

Tags: color-management, display-calibration, white-balance, ipad

I just transferred some photos from my Macbook to my iPod Touch and my iPad 1st gen. I found that photos on my iPad are a tad warmer than they are on my Macbook and my iPod Touch. Has anyone experienced this before?

Comment: All displays differ. I have 2 identical displays on my desk, same model number and one is warmer and the other one cooler with the same settings. Hardware calibration is possible but not on iPad. Is there a chance you have a screen protector installed? Like the ZAGG? There are reports that these cover turn yellow over time and make the display darker/warmer.

Comment: Yeah I do have a screen protector installed. Oh well. It's a minute difference, but I notice it, perhaps because I spend lots of time in Lightroom. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different displays ship with manufacturing tolerances which will give each unit fractionally differing colour output; in addition to this, manufacturers may choose to ship with factory default colour settings. To complicate matters further, the capacitive covering over the iPad screen may introduce a colour cast of its own.

The only way to get reliable colour reproduction is to use a colourimeter to calibrate the screen, and this is now available if you have a [Spyder](http://spyder.datacolor.com/), who now have an application available on the [iTunes AppStore](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/spydergallery/id432310625?mt=8&ls=1).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess nothing could be done about this.

Comment: @rabbid Apparently, there is now a solution available, so I've updated the answer appropriately - best of luck...

Comment: just fixed both links, but my edits need to be peer reviewed to actually work.

Comment: Cool. It's worth noting that the Spyder app can only adjust its _own_ output and can't affect other iPad apps.

Comment: @mattdm - this makes it much less worthy to buy a colorimeter for the iPad, unless one is planning to also calibrate all his other screens.